# Laravel 5.4 models relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.4, has-many-through

I'm struggling to find a way to output all **NORMS** (last table on the right) where **JURISDICTIONS** (last table on the left) is equal to a parameter given by a select (i did this using eloquent hasManyThrough, and i did output all norms related to that specific Jurisdiction) and where, and here comes the problem, these Norms belongs to a specific category also passes by a select (the smallest table in the image, **DETAILREDACS**).

**NORMS** and **DETAILSREDACS** are ManyToMany related.

[image]

Here are the two main attempts:

[image]

How can i achieve this? I've tried joining tables, but i'm probably doing something wrong.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Thanks!!!

Comment: In general it is frowned upon to post code as images, whenever possible please post code as text.

Comment: I'm sorry Alex Harris, i'll fix it!